# Как вызвать sql запрос и передать параметр из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Всем привет. Возникли проблемы при составление корректного SQL - Запроса.
Как вызвать sql query и передать параметр на вход из другой таблицы?

У меня есть сложный sql query, записанный как query с именем qryARAT2B_EXT и получающий параметр PАРАМ.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         *
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               *,
               firstStudy,
               ABS(DATEDIFF('d', firstStudy, Check_Date)) as diff
            FROM
               (
                  SELECT
                     *,
                     (
                        SELECT
                           TOP 1 Check_Date
                        FROM
                           qryARAT2B
                        WHERE
                           PATNR = [PАРАМ]
                        ORDER BY
                           Check_Date
                     )
                     AS firstStudy
                  FROM
                     (
                        SELECT
                           *
                        FROM
                           qryARAT2B
                        WHERE
                           PATNR = [PАРАМ]
                     )
                     AS myPatientsWithStudy
               )
               AS myPatientsFirstStudy
         )
      WHERE
         diff = 0
   )
   AS T1
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            *
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  *,
                  firstStudy,
                  ABS(DATEDIFF('d', firstStudy, Check_Date)) as diff
               FROM
                  (
                     SELECT
                        *,
                        (
                           SELECT
                              TOP 1 Check_Date
                           FROM
                              qryARAT2B
                           WHERE
                              PATNR = [PАРАМ]
                           ORDER BY
                              Check_Date
                        )
                        AS firstStudy
                     FROM
                        (
                           SELECT
                              *
                           FROM
                              qryARAT2B
                           WHERE
                              PATNR = [PАРАМ]
                        )
                        AS myPatientsWithStudy
                  )
                  AS myPatientsFirstStudy
            )
         WHERE
            diff = 4
      )
      As T2
      ON T1.PATNR = T2.PATNR
```

Когда я его открываю из ms-access он у меня запрашивает значение [PAPAM] и выдает результат.

мне нужно написать sql в котором я мог бы передать параметр PAPAM.

```
SELECT * FROM qryARAT2B_EXT2 WHERE PAPAM = 1
```

Но ms-access все равно его запрашивает, может есть какой-то специальный синтакс?

Comment: Он у вас встречается во многих местах. если запрашивает - значит где то в запросе он остался.

Comment: У Вас изначальный синтаксис запроса требует ввода параметра. Пытаясь извне передать параметр внутрь подзапроса, Вы фактически хотите использовать его как коррелированный, но MS Access подобных конструкций не понимает в принципе. Так что корректируйте текст своего "сложного sql query".